# scrapy - CrawlSpider is not executing my callback

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I created a spider to gather usernames on scratch.mit.edu.
It successfully navigates to the profile pages, but it doesn't run the callback function. I think that it might have something to do with how I am writing my allow attribute.

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ForumnSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'forumn'
    allowed_domains = ['scratch.mit.edu']
    start_urls = [
        'https://scratch.mit.edu/users/accountcraft123/'
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(),
        ),
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                allow=('/users/'),
            ),
            callback='parse_item',
        ),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('This is a profile page. %s', response.url)
        response.xpath('//div[@class="header-text"]/h2/text()').get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@iL0g1c, it's working now so far

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ForumnSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'forumn'
    allowed_domains = ['scratch.mit.edu']
    start_urls = ['https://scratch.mit.edu/users/accountcraft123/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/users/.*')), follow=True,callback='parse'),

    )


    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('This is a profile page. %s', response.url)
        response.xpath('//div[@class="header-text"]/h2/text()').get()
```

Comment: thank you. the callback seems to be working now. the only thing i changed was the callback name. since parse is already used in scrapy, i renamed it to parse_item to prevent overwrite.